# Most efficient way to check if elements in an array have changed

Tags: c, arrays, performance, hash

I have an array in c and I need to perform some operation only if the elements in an array have changed. However the time and memory taken for this is very important. I realized that an efficient way to do this would probably be to hash all the elements of the array and compare the result with the previous result. If they match that means the elements dont change. I would however like to know if this is the most efficient way of doing things. Also since the array is only 8 bytes long(1 byte for each element) which hashing function would be least time consuming?

The elements in an array are actually being received from another microcontroller. So they may or may not change depending on whether what the other micro-controller measured is the same or not

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: "compare the result with the previous result.  ...match that means the elements dont change" is incorrect.  If the hash is different, then the arrays are different.  If hashes the same they _may_ be the same.

Comment: Can you access the array exclusively through a function?  If so then it's as simple as setting  a flag

Comment: store and compare 8 bytes. It's not compute intensive

Comment: If the array is only 8 bytes long then simply keeping a copy and comparing is almost certainly the fastest and most storage-efficient.  That is, if you can't simply keep a flag that gets set when it's changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you weren't tied to a simple array, you could create a "MRU" List of structures where the structure could contain a flag that indicates if the item was changed since it was last inspected.

Every time an item changes set the "changed flag" and move it to the head of the list. When you need to check for the changed items you traverse the list from the head and unset the changed flags and stopping at the first element with its change flag not set.

Sorry, I missed the part about the array being only 8 bytes long. With that info and with the new info from your edit, I'm thinking the previous suggestion is not ideal.

If the array is only 8-bytes long why not just cache a copy of the previous array and compare it to the new array received?

Below is a clarification of my comment about "shortcutting" the compares. How you implement this would depend on what the sizeof(int) is on the platform used.

Using a 64-bit integer you could get away with one compare to determine if the array has changed. For example:

```
#define ARR_SIZE 8

unsigned char cachedArr[ARR_SIZE];
unsigned char targetArr[ARR_SIZE];

unsigned int *ic = (unsigned int *)cachedArr;
unsigned int *it = (unsigned int *)targetArr;

// This assertion needs to be true for this implementation to work 
// correctly.
assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(cachedArr));

/* 
** ... 
** assume initialization and other suff here 
** leading into the main loop that is receiving the target array data.
** ...
*/

if (*ic != *it)
{
    // Target array has changed; find out which element(s) changed.
    // If you only cared that there was a change and did not care 
    // to know which specific element(s) had changed you could forego
    // this loop altogether.
    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (cachedArr[i] != targetArr[i])
        {
            // Do whatever needs to be done based on the i'th element
            // changed
        }
    }

    // Cache the array again since it has changed.
    memcpy(cachedArr, targetArr, sizeof(cachedArr));
}
// else no change to the array
```

If the native integer size was smaller than 64-bit you could use the same theory, but you'd have to loop over the array `sizeof(cachedArr) / sizeof(unsigned int)` times; and there would be a worst-case scenario involved (but isn't there always) if the change was in the last chunk tested.

It should be noted that with doing any char to integer type casting you may need to take into consideration alignment (if the char data is aligned to the appropriate word-size boundary).

Thinking further upon this however, it might be better altogether to just unroll the loop yourself and do:

```
if (cachedArr[0] != targetArr[0])
{
    doElement0ChangedWork();
}
if (cachedArr[1] != targetArr[1])
{
    doElement1ChangedWork();
}
if (cachedArr[2] != targetArr[2])
{
    doElement2ChangedWork();
}
if (cachedArr[3] != targetArr[3])
{
    doElement3ChangedWork();
}
if (cachedArr[4] != targetArr[4])
{
    doElement4ChangedWork();
}
if (cachedArr[5] != targetArr[5])
{
    doElement5ChangedWork();
}
if (cachedArr[6] != targetArr[6])
{
    doElement6ChangedWork();
}
if (cachedArr[7] != targetArr[7])
{
    doElement7ChangedWork();
}
```

Again, depending on whether or not knowing which specific element(s) changed that could be tightened up. This would result in more instruction memory needed but eliminates the loop overhead (the good old memory versus speed trade-off).

As with anything time/memory related test, measure, compare, tweak and repeat until desired results are achieved.

Comment: The only reason I didnt want to go there is I would have to keep comparing the bytes continously and this runs in the main loop of the MCU. So I was searching for a more effcient way of doing this.

Comment: What is the size of an integer on your platform? You can attempt to shortcut the compares by casting a pointer to your array as an unsigned integer and comparing in chunks. Only when the chunks differ do you then have to compare that chunk byte-by-byte.

Comment: Think about this:  The smallest hash you might reasonably use is 4 bytes.  So to use a hash you'd have to fetch 8 bytes, hash into 4, fetch the old 4-byte hash, and compare.  So you fetch at least 12 with the hash vs 16 with the compare, and the hash is much more complex.  It would be amazing if the hash were a performance winner.

Comment: I wasn't talking about hashing. I've attempted to clarify this in a previous edit.

Answer (score 1):

> only if the elements in an array have changed

Who else but you is going to change them? You can just keep track of whether you've made a change since the last time you did the operation.

If you don't want to do that (perhaps because it'd require recording changes in too many places, or because the record-keeping would take too much time, or because another thread or other hardware is messing with the array), just save the old contents of the array in a separate array. It's only 8 bytes. When you want to see whether anything has changed, compare the current array to the copy element-by-element.

Comment: Not really. The elements in an array are actually being received from another microcontroller. So they nay or may not change depending on whther what the other microcontroller measured is the same or not

Comment: @user1667307: Then just keep a copy of what the array used to look like. It's only 8 bytes. (Even if it was bigger than 8 bytes, a hash wouldn't cut it unless you were okay with false positives.)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the elements will only change if the code changed them.

Maybe this data can be changed by another user? Otherwise you would know that you had changed an entry.

As far as the hash function, there are only 2^8 = 256 different values that this array can take. A hash function won't really help here. Also, a hash function has to be computed, which costs memory so I don't think that will work for your application.

I would just compare bits until you find one has changed. If one has changed, the you will check 4 bits on average before you that your array has changed (assuming that each bit is equally likely to change).

If one hasn't changed, that is worst case scenario and you will have to check all eight bits to conclude that none have changed.

Answer (score 1):

If array only 8 bytes long, you can treat it as if it is a long long type number. Suppose original array is char data[8].

```
long long * pData = (logn long *)data;
long long olddata = *pData;

if ( olddata != *pData )
{
      // detect which one changed
}
```

I mean, this way you operate all data in one shot, this is much faster than access each element using index. hash is slower n this case.

Answer (score 0):

If it is byte oriented with only eight elements, doing an XOR function would be more efficient than any other comparison.

If ((LocalArray[0] ^ received Array [0]) & (LocalArray[1] ^ received Array [1]) &  ...)

{

//Yes it is changed

}